# Rails RSpec like testing in Google Go

Tags: go

I am looking for behavior oriented, English sounding like testing utility for `Go`. Something like RSpec in Ruby or Jasmine in JavaScript.

I have found `go-spec` on GitHub, but its broken (hasn't been updated in 2 years and does NOT work with Go 1.

Comment: I think most gophers prefer the table driven test suites so finding something which fits your needs might be difficult. Do you think the "idiomatic" table driven tests are hard to understand, maintain or write?

Comment: You may find that you can update go-spec to work with Go 1.1 with very little effort, using `go fix`. I haven't used it myself but it's supposed to make upgrades like that easy.

Comment: I only know Rspec style, but Ill give table test suites a try. Why not, I'm open for new things, especially if they are idiomatic for that language. Thanks @Volker

Comment: I just learned I could auto fix @ install process, like `go get -fix github.com/author/package`, so don't need to run go fix later on. Thanks for mentioning gofix @MatrixFrog

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426703/which-is-the-best-bdd-tdd-testing-library-for-go/19426768#19426768

Answer (score 8):

I authored [GoConvey](http://smartystreets.github.io/goconvey/), which includes the added bonus of an auto-updating UI that runs in your browser.

Comment: Any advice on getting desktop notifications to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/25811/chrome-desktop-notifications-use-notify-osd

Comment: I have to say goconvey is amazing. It is part of our test routinely now.

Answer (score 7):

Ginkgo is a BDD-style Golang testing framework: http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/